# dynamically assign a factor/string name inside a function in R

Tags: r, function

I want to output multiple PNG files and I am clueless on how to name them. Basically I want to make multiple word clouds using one data frame. One column contains the data from which word clouds have to be made and one column contains categories for which word clouds are to be made. I have written a function to create a single word cloud. Now I want to save all the word clouds in one go using tapply (or something else) and each word cloud should get a name like `category_name.png`
This is a reproducible version of the code that I have written

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

String_column = rep(c("hello round world", "beautiful round world", "good girls world", "unfair mean world", "hi girls hello","sad girls sorry"),6)
Category_column = rep(c("Neutral", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg", "Neutral","Neg"),6)

getCloudData <- function(StrCol,CatCol){
    answer_text <- paste(StrCol, collapse=" ") 
    answer_source = VectorSource(answer_text)
    corpus = Corpus(answer_source)
    dtmWords = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
    matrixWords = as.matrix(dtmWords)

    freqWords = colSums(matrixWords)
    freqWords = sort(freqWords, decreasing = TRUE)
    words <- names(freqWords)
    png("C:\\Users\\GSinghal\\Downloads\\Text Mining\\catagory_xyz.png")
    wordcloud(words[1:3], freqWords[1:3])
    dev.off()
}

getCloudData(String_column,Category_column)
tapply(String_column, Category_column,getCloudData)
```

Now when I use tapply I want all three files to be saved with names Neutral.png, Pos.png and Neg.png. Actual data contains around 11,000 strings and around 20 to 65 categories.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to do, but I think you need to rewrite the function to use a single value from your category column and then run a `for` loop to iterate that function over the unique values of `Category_column`. So you get one plot per value of `Category_column`, each one of which uses all values of `String_column`. Does that sound right?

Comment: Thanks ulfelder, I ended up writing a code in the way you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your function a bit, and using `data.table` instead of `tapply` can work:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Cat_Col = Category_column, Str_Col = String_column)

getCloudData <- function(StrCol,Category){
  answer_text <- paste(StrCol, collapse=" ") 
  answer_source = VectorSource(answer_text)
  corpus = Corpus(answer_source)
  dtmWords = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
  matrixWords = as.matrix(dtmWords)
  freqWords = colSums(matrixWords)
  freqWords = sort(freqWords, decreasing = TRUE)
  words <- names(freqWords)
  png(paste(unique(Category),".png", sep = "")) #changed this part
  wordcloud(words[1:3], freqWords[1:3])
  graphics.off() #instead of dev.off
}

DT[ , getCloudData(Str_Col,Cat_Col), by = "Cat_Col"]
```

This uses the `by` function of data.table to apply your `getCloudData` function across all categories.

You should then see all of the images in your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks Chris, though I implemented a solution using a for loop, your solution looks better. Just wanted to know if we are passing category in the function, why do we need to use unique(Category) in the png function.

Comment: @GauravSinghal The function will take a column of data as its input for both arguments. Because R is vecotrized, if we just use `png(paste(Category,".png", sep = ""))` it will output `Norm.png` as many times as there are rows for the category